# In Java, is it possible to find out which port number is used by a known PID in UNIX systems?

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the best code/class in Java that can capture the port number by supplying with a known process number (PID) in Unix systems, ie Linux, Solaris and AIX. I checked with the `Socket` class but it doesn't seem to support this solution?

Anyone knows the better way to reach this solution?

Comment: Well the dirty way would be to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`

Comment: @SebastianWalla how would that help?

Comment: Why do you have to write Java code for this when `lsof`, `netstat`, and `ps` already exist?

Comment: @OP What you mean might be a combination of lsof+tcpdump, but it is only my guess. Kindly re-phrase your question so that it make sense.

Comment: you mean tcp sockets or unix sockets you want to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`

For Example the fallowing code shows how to get tcp socket of process with PID

**2046**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Process p=null;
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    String command= "netstat  -p ";
    try{
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            if(line.matches("^tcp.*2406.*"))
            output.append(line + "\n");

            //reader.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     System.out.println(output);
}
```

output for this in my system was

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.239:52956     sc-in-f188.1e100.n:5228 ESTABLISHED 2406/chrome
```

we know the socket here is **52956** you can further parse the string for finding socket

refer

[how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/)

Comment: The  solution you showed above is working for me. netstat is a good choice as it is available on most UNIX systems, specifically Linux, Solaris and AIX. I think `netstat -pntu` is probably the way to go as it reads information from both tcp and udp.